# How To Search For a DataPoint on the X-Axis, and then be able to change the Y Value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, charts

I am creating a chart that currently generates different data points by adding to x-axis values in a loop in one series.

In another series I want to be able to:

- Search to see if the series "Total Cost" has a data point at the same point as a string "starttime"
- if the chart has no values at all, addXY of that point to the series
- if the chart has a value at "starttime", add a value to the current Y value
- if the chart has no value at "starttime", addXY point to the series

Here is the code I have been trying to use so far:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

// ...

public DateTime starttime;
public DateTime endtime;
public DateTime totaltime;

private void comboBoxStart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string format = "HH:mm";
        starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBoxStart.Text, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBoxTotalTime.Text != "")
    {
        string format = "HH:mm";
        totaltime = DateTime.ParseExact(
            comboBoxFinish.Text, format, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        chartTimespan.Series.Add(textBoxName.Text);             

        while(starttime <= endtime)
        {                
            chartTimespan.Series[textBoxName.Text].Points.AddXY(starttime, 6);
            starttime = starttime.AddMinutes(15);

            DataPoint DataPointX = chartTimespan.Series[textBoxName.Text].Points
                .FindByValue((starttime).ToOADate(), "X");

            if(chartTimespan.Series["Total Cost"].Points.Contains(null))
            {
                chartTimespan.Series["Total Cost"].Points.AddXY(starttime, 6);
            }
            else if (!(chartTimespan.Series["Total Cost"].Points.FindByValue((starttime).ToOADate(), "X") == null))
            {
                chartTimespan.Series["Total Cost"].Points.;
            }
            else
            {
                chartTimespan.Series["Total Cost"].Points.AddXY(starttime, 6);
            }    
        }

        chartTimespan.Legends.Add(textBoxName.Text);
        chartTimespan.Series[textBoxName.Text].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    }
    textBoxName.Text = "";
    comboBoxStart.Text = "";
    comboBoxFinish.Text="";
    textBoxTotalTime.Text = "";
}
```

Cheers for any help, or if you think I should be using a different approach!

Comment: Please add a few word on what is or isn't working! Also: You search for ToOADate datetimes; is that really what you have added to the 1st series?

Comment: The first doesn't add only if there's nothing there (it adds all the time), the "else if" statement reads an error of "specified value is outside the range of values", and I don't know how to proceed with the coding for adding a value onto the existing y value of the data points it's searching for...see the extra lines of code for how "starttime" is formatted, but I believe that's what I'm adding, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for values inside the chart, which can get tricky at times due to formatting, I prefer to use `chart.Series["name"].Points.Databind` with a more managable collection. In my experience it makes sense when you work with dynamic data; Rather than storing the data in the chart you have the chart display (processed) data.

For this type of solution first fashion some type of data-object that will hold relevant values:

```
public class ChartItem
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public ChartItem(DateTime time, double value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Time = time;
    }
}
```

And in your `Form` you have something like:

```
public List<ChartItem> chartItems;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    chartItems = new List<ChartItem>();
    chartItems.Add(new ChartItem(DateTime.Today, 1);
    chartItems.Add(new ChartItem(DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(15), 2); // "Or something"
    ...
    chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(chartItems, "Time", "Value", "");
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
}
```

And finally to add a value in your `private void pictureBox1_MouseUp`:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

const double valueToAdd = 1;

ChartItem item = chartItems.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Time == time);

if (item == null) // No previous time in series
{   
    item = new ChartItem(time, valueToAdd);
    chartItems.Add(item);
}
else // Add to previous time
    item.Value += valueToAdd;

chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(chartItems, "Time", "Value", ""); // Update chart
```